# How to plot grouped, stacked bar charts in R to show if the proportions of data are homogeneous across groups

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

Suppose you have 3 sets, numbered from 1 to 3.
Each set contains unique ID's associated to categorical active/inactive labels for variables A, B, C, D.
You want to make plots that show, for each variable, the *proportions* of active/inactive labels side to side in the 3 sets, to show if they are homogeneous or not.

The only way I could come up with to do this was the following:

```
# Simulate data: 3 different sets, each with 4 different variables, each with different proportions of labels
sets = c("1", "2", "3")
variables = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
labs = c("active", "inactive")
N = 10000
set.seed(1325)
d = data.frame("set" = sample(sets, N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7)),
               "variable" = sample(variables, N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.15, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4)))
d["label"] = "x"
for (v in variables) {
  vw = which(d[["variable"]] == v)
  vp = runif(1, 0.1, 0.6)
  d[vw, "label"] = sample(labs, length(vw), replace = TRUE, prob = c(vp, 1 - vp))
}
d["ID"] <- 1:N

s = aggregate(ID ~ set + variable + label, d, length)
s.l = aggregate(ID ~ set + variable, d, length)
colnames(s.l)[3] <- "ID.l"
s = merge(s, s.l)
s["frac"] = with(s, ID / ID.l)

op = par()
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (v in variables) {
  barplot(frac ~ label + set, s, subset = variable == v, col = c("blue", "orange"), main = v)
}
par(op)
```

[image]

Given how the labels are assigned in the code, their proportions are different for the different variables, but homogeneous across the sets.

To show what happens when the proportions are not homogeneous:

```
# change the proportion of labels for one set
sw = which(d[["set"]] == 1)
d.u = d
d.u[sw, "label"] = sample(labs, length(sw), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.05, 1 - 0.05))

s.u = aggregate(ID ~ set + variable + label, d.u, length)
s.u.l = aggregate(ID ~ set + variable, d.u, length)
colnames(s.u.l)[3] <- "ID.l"
s.u = merge(s.u, s.u.l)
s.u["frac"] = with(s.u, ID / ID.l)

op = par()
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (v in variables) {
  barplot(frac ~ label + set, s.u, subset = variable == v, col = c("blue", "orange"), main = v)
}
par(op)
```

[image]

**Question**: do you think this can be done or represented better / more efficiently?

In particular, I would have thought that the `aggregate` and division part might be already built-in for some type of plot.
And I am wondering if using `mfrow` and plotting an array of separate plots is any good, or if there is some way to make a more cohesive lattice or grid of plots by using `variable` as one of the parameters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the double `aggregate` calls, consider `by` to split data frame by *variable* and run `xtabs` + `proportions` on each subset:

**`boxplot` formula style**

```r
op <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
tbls <- by(d, d$variable, FUN=function(sub) {
  tbl <- xtabs(~ label + set, sub)
  props <- data.frame(proportions(tbl, 2))
  barplot(Freq ~ label + set, props, 
          col = c("blue", "orange"), 
          main = sub$variable[1])
})
par(op)
```

**`barplot` matrix style**

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
tbls <- by(d, d$variable, FUN=function(sub) {
  tbl <- xtabs(~ label + set, sub)
  props <- proportions(tbl, 2)
  barplot(props, xlab = "set", ylab = "frac",
          col = c("blue", "orange"), 
          main = sub$variable[1])
})
par(op)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know (or recall) this `proportion` function. Only change, I think `xtabs` should be run with nothing on the lhs of the formula, otherwise we are summing the `ID` indices, not counting them. And indeed, the plots look different. For the rest, I take it you confirm that there is nothing more cohesive, so `mfrow` is inevitable?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, per docs, lhs is optional. Not sure about your last question. `mfrow` presents plots in a grid layout, otherwise all plots display in own plot. Do note: `by` is an apply family loop (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`).