# How to plot grouped, stacked bar charts in python to show if the proportions of data are homogeneous across groups

Tags: python, plot

I need to do in `python` something similar to what I did in `R`:

[How to plot grouped, stacked bar charts in R to show if the proportions of data are homogeneous across groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72206897/6376297)

Here are my attempts so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from numpy.random import default_rng

# Simulate data: 3 different sets, each with 4 different variables, each with different proportions of labels
sets = ["1", "2", "3"]
variables = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
labs = ["active", "inactive"]
N = 10000
rng = default_rng(1325)
d = pd.DataFrame({"set" : rng.choice(sets, size = N, replace = True, p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]),
                "variable" : rng.choice(variables, size = N, replace = True, p = [0.15, 0.25, 0.2, 0.4])})
d["label"] = "x"
for v in variables :
    vw = d[d["variable"] == v].index
    vp = rng.uniform(low = 0.1, high = 0.6, size = 1).item(0)
    d.loc[vw,"label"] = rng.choice(labs, size = len(vw), replace = True, p = [vp, 1 - vp])

d["ID"] = range(N)

d.sort_values(by = ['set','variable','label'], inplace = True)
```

I was hoping to be able to do this by `sns.displot` with `kind = 'hist', stat = 'probability'`. No joy:

```
sns.displot(data = d,
            x = 'set',            
            kind = 'hist',
            stat = 'probability',
            col = 'variable',            
            hue = 'label',
            multiple = 'stack',
            fill = True,
            discrete = True
            )
```

[image]

It looks like the margins that are taken for calculating the 'probability' are not by variable and set, despite those being the columns by which the data are grouped.

So I made the summary myself, like I had to do in `R`:

```
s = d.groupby(['variable','set','label']).count().reset_index()
s_l = s.groupby(['variable','set']).sum().reset_index()
s_l.rename(columns = {'ID' : 'ID_l'}, inplace = True)
s = s.merge(s_l)
s["frac"] = s['ID'] / s['ID_l']
```

And then the closest I could find was `sns.catplot`:

```
sns.catplot(data = s,
            x = 'set',
            y = 'frac',
            hue = 'label',
            kind = 'bar',
            col = 'variable')
```

[image]

which is sort of OK for what I need to show, but it does not stack the bars, which makes it a bit more difficult to interpret.

`sns.displot` with `kind = 'hist'` would of course no longer work, because it would just count the occurrences and find 50:50 for all cases.

**Question**: any idea how I could achieve something like I did in `R`, namely stacked bars showing the proportion of labels across sets, split by variable?

Comment: have you tried `sns.histplot` with `multiple=stack` and `stat=probability` or `stat=density`? See documentation for more info https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot

Comment: @Zeitproblem : yes, it's the first one I tried (within displot, because I need to separate by variable). And it does not yield bars summing up to 1.